# If x is not an element of $m$, then $m+(x) = A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $m$ be a maximal ideal of $A$.

Let $x$ be a non-unit. If x is not an element of $m$, then $m+(x) = A$.

I have problem understanding $m+(x) = A$.  Why is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $m+(x)$ is an ideal, that it contains $m$, and that it contains $x\notin m$. So we have $m\subsetneq m+(x)$. Now use that $m$ is maximal.

Comment: Ah I see, it just comes from the definition of $m$ is a maximal ideal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$I=m+(x)$ is an ideal. It is strictly larger than the maximal ideals $M$. What could possibly be $I$?